# How to add items to lightning tree component through controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

I am trying to add items to the lightning tree component through the controller js file on the click of a button. I already have all the data pulled in on the load event. What happens now is it just loads the labels expanded with no items.
Here is my js code:

```
    loadSuitesForMDU : function(component, event, helper) {     
    var streetName = event.getSource().get("v.title");
    var city = event.getSource().get("v.name");
    var selectedMduUnits = component.get("v.mduInfoForChartAndRightContent");        
    var unitsToFilter = selectedMduUnits.filter(x => { return x.Name === streetName && x.sumchans__city__c === city; });
    var filterNn = unitsToFilter.filter(x => { return x.sumchans__accountNumber__c === undefined && x.sumchans__contactNumber__c === undefined; });
    var filterCc = unitsToFilter.filter(x => { return x.sumchans__accountNumber__c === undefined && x.sumchans__contactNumber__c != undefined; });
    var filterAa = unitsToFilter.filter(x => { return x.sumchans__status__c === 'On-billing'; });
    var items = [{
        "label": "Never",
        "expanded": true,
        "items": [filterNn]
    }, {
        "label": "Active",
        "expanded": true,
        "items": [filterAa]
    }];        
    component.set("v.suitesList",items);     

},
```

Here is the markup:

```
<lightning:tree items="{! v.suitesList }" header="Suites"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array filter method always returns a new Array. 
You are assigning nested array to "items" change 
`"items" : [filterNn]` to `"items" : filterNn`
and
`"items" : [filterAa]` to `"items" : filterAa`

Comment: @Nitesh tried it still the same, not showing any data.

Comment: @Sumchans have you tried console logging filterNn and filterAa?

Comment: I got the original post edited with pic from console log

Comment: @Sumchans Does filterNn elements have "label" key in them?

Comment: no they don't have label

Comment: @Sumchans "label" is required for items. check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/documentation

Comment: Oh okay. How do we then dynamically load data?

Comment: @Sumchans Use array forEach or forloop to iterate over them and assign Label.

Comment: Thanks @Nithesh. Will try that tomorrow and let you know.